# Convert react form component into typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react form component , it is working in `JavaScript` perfectly, I would like to convert it into `TypeScript` but I get this error: `Property '_title' does not exist on type 'FormComp'`. The component is like:

```
class FormComp extends React.Component<{}> {
  constructor(props: any) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {};
 }
 handleCreate(event: any) {
   event.preventDefault();

   var title = this._title.value;
   const temp = { title: title };
   // This temp object will be send to backend by ajax call 
   .
   . 
   .
   }
   render() {
     return (
      <div className="col-md-12">
       <input
       type="text"
       className="col-sm-3 form-control"
       placeholder="Title"
       ref={(c) => (this._title = c)}
       ></input>
       <button
         className="btn btn-primary"
         onClick={this.handleCreate.bind(this)}
       >
        Create
      </button>
        );
      }
     }
```

How can I convert this component into `TypeScript` component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using this._title, you have to define it for TypeScript. To do that:

```
class FormComp extends React.Component<{}> {
  _title: string; // or other type
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , I got a new error , error is : `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'`

Comment: I wrote string as an example, you have to use the actual type of _title. In your case, it may be (may also not be, since I don't know what the _title is and what data it contains):
`interface Title { value: string; }`
Then, you can use `_title: Title;` in your class.

Comment: The type is correct I guess, where I have to put this `interface Title {     value: string; }`? In the function ? or in the class ?

Comment: @Tjax you can put it outside the class or you can define it in other file, where you implement all types and then import it.

Comment: I put that  outside the class but still have this error `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.` related to this line `var title = this._title.value;`

Comment: Did you change the line `_title: string;` to the `_title: Title;`?

Comment: Thanks a lot , now it works and I do not have that error .

Comment: Just one more question , I got a new error like `Type 'HTMLInputElement | null' is not assignable to type 'Title'.`

Comment: Seems like you're trying to assign Input Element to the _title. If you assigned _title to be of type Title (which is `interface Title { ... }`), you can't assign anything else to it but something with the type of Title. In TypeScript, you can't change types of variables. You can assign _title to be of type `HTMLInputElement | null`, by writing `_title: HTMLInputElement | null`